# Discord Bot Crashing with no errors

Tags: python, discord

The issue I am having is that this code will work for four to five minutes, if the text file updates, the message will be displayed on discord. But what happens is that either it runs out of memory or some other issue arises and the bot just stops and will no longer pick up messages.

the text file is getting inputs from a source and added to at random times. It also does not leave any error message.

```
    import discord
    import asyncio
    from discord.ext import commands
    import time


    global count

    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

    def get_msg(): #Retrieves the last message from the text file
        global last
        global logs
        logs = open('msg.txt','r')
        msgs = logs.readlines()
        logs.close()
        last = msgs[len(msgs)-1]

    def line_count(): #Retrieves the amount of lines in the text file
        global count
        r = open("msg.txt", 'r')
        j = r.readlines()
        r.close()
        count = 0

        for line in j:

            count += 1
        r.close()
        return count

    async def run(): #checks if the amount of lines has changed, if it has; displays message
        global count

        ct = line_count()
        oc = ct
        await bot.wait_until_ready()

        while True:

            if ct != oc:
                oc = ct
                get_msg()
                prep = "Incoming: " + last
                await bot.send_message(discord.Object('******'),prep)

                oc = ct
            else:
                ct = line_count()




    bot.loop.create_task(run())        
    bot.run('***********')
```

Comment: jersten I have no idea how to do that

Comment: sorry jersten but can you explain the f, the s, and the 10000